# Music in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I'm using the SimpleAudioEngine for cocos2d and when one track finished I would like to play another.

It only allows one background music to be preloaded at a time though. Would it be ridiculous to 'join' 2 .mp3s using audacity and then just convert to .caf and preload the whole thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly not ridiculous, but be wary about how much memory your sounds require.

Also, why the conversion to .caf? You can play .mp3s. Is this just for compression?

Comment: Thanks. I asummed caf was good just to reduce the app size. Question about music memory consumption though, does the memory consumed equate to the size of the uncompressed mp3?